# actionscript 3 - Error #2136 - simple issue

Tags: actionscript-3

This is extremely basic, but to help me understand could someone please explain why this doesn't work. Trying to call a function from one as file to another, and get the following error.

```
Error: Error #2136: The SWF file file:///test/Main.swf contains invalid data.
at code::Main()[C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\test\code\Main.as:12]
Error opening URL 'file:///test/Main.swf'
```

Main.as

```
package code {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.*;

        import code.Enemy;  

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Main()
            {
                var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
            }

            public function test():void
            {
                trace("Test");
            }
      }
}
```

Enemy.as

```
package code {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.*;

        import code.Main;

    public class Enemy extends Main {

        public function Enemy() {

            var main:Main = new Main();
            main.test();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Main` is your document class, you can't instantiate it. That might explain the SWF invalid data error.

What it looks like you are trying to do is access a function on `Main` from your `Enemy`. To do that you just need a reference to `Main` from inside your `Enemy` class. If you add the `Enemy` instance to the display list you can probably use `root` or `parent` to get a reference to `Main`. You could also pass a reference to `Main` through the constructor of your `Enemy` class:

```
public class Main {
    public function Main() {
        new Enemy(this);
    }
    public function test():void {
        trace("test");
    }
}

public class Enemy {
    public function Enemy(main:Main) {
        main.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the constructor of the class **Main** you are creating the Object of **Enemy**. In the constructor of **Enemy** you are creating the Object of **Main**. Hence it continues to create those two objects until there is **Stack overflow**. It never reaches to the line where you have `main.test();`

Answer (score 0):

if you wana get data frome main.as you can use the static var.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        // i well get this var in my Enemy as.
        public var i:uint=1021;

        public function txtuto() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }

}`
// the Enemy.as
`package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class Enemy extends MovieClip {

        public static var tx:Main = new Main;
        public function Enemy() {
            trace(tx.i);
        }
    }

}
```

good luck.